# Eclipse - Edit conflict (SVN) gives Resource does not exist

Tags: eclipse, svn

We are a team of five developers. Two of us get this message when trying to resolve a conflict in Eclipse. The other three don't.

> "Resource '/xxxx.java.mine' does not exist.

[image]

Resolving the conflict in Tortoise works fine. Reinstalling the svn-plugin doens't help either

Setup for all team members

- Windows 10 (x64)
- Eclipse Mars 2 (4.5.2)
- Subclipse 1.10.13

Anyone seen this error before? and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Clean the workspace
- Delete the project from local drive
- Re-import the project from SVN

Comment: has someone from you team deleted a file from local eclipse which was already committed into svn

Comment: no. No files have been deleted. Happens on all files where there is a conflict

Comment: 1) Clean the workspace  
 2) Delete the project from local drive 
3) Re-import the project from SVN